# Java Oracle oracle.sql.ARRAY errors

Tags: java, sql, arrays, oracle

I am using array in oracle db and call CallableStatement to execute stored procedure.

This time I included blob type in the array:

```
create or replace type My_ARRAY AS object(
_ID  NUMBER(10),
DOCUMNT blob)
```

After creating the ArrayDescriptor and in the java Class I used **InputStream** ( **java.sql.Blob** too) call

```
new ARRAY(varcharAdd, getConnection(), addArray);
```

it catch an error, in the debug mode `e.printStackTrace();` was showing ASCII system code and my system start to make sound : bib's.
for the case of **java.sql.Blob** it throw this message:

```
java.sql.SQLException: Fail to convert to internal representation: javax.sql.rowset.serial.SerialBlob@d316ee
    at oracle.jdbc.oracore.OracleTypeBLOB.toDatum(OracleTypeBLOB.java:71)
    at oracle.sql.StructDescriptor.toOracleArray(StructDescriptor.java:723)
    at oracle.sql.StructDescriptor.toArray(StructDescriptor.java:1298)
    at oracle.sql.STRUCT.<init>(STRUCT.java:167)
    at oracle.sql.OracleSQLOutput.getSTRUCT(OracleSQLOutput.java:125)
    at oracle.sql.STRUCT.toSTRUCT(STRUCT.java:502)
    at oracle.jdbc.oracore.OracleTypeADT.toDatum(OracleTypeADT.java:329)
    at oracle.jdbc.oracore.OracleTypeADT.toDatumArray(OracleTypeADT.java:373)
    at oracle.jdbc.oracore.OracleTypeUPT.toDatumArray(OracleTypeUPT.java:110)
    at oracle.sql.ArrayDescriptor.toOracleArray(ArrayDescriptor.java:1240)
    at oracle.sql.ARRAY.<init>(ARRAY.java:103)
```

Have anybody one use blob Oracle array and face this kind of issue.

Comment: please share your exception stack trace as well.

Comment: i just edited my question. Please check

Answer (score 0):

The problem exactly was the type of the blob we are writing in the stream, **InputStream** and **java.sql.Blob** was not correct we must use **oracle.sql.BLOB**

```
public static final void writeBlob(SQLOutput stream, byte[] value) throws SQLException {
        if (value != null) {
            oracle.sql.BLOB blob = oracle.sql.BLOB.getEmptyBLOB();
            blob.setBytes(value);
            stream.writeBlob(blob);
        } else {
            stream.writeObject(null);
        }
    }

    public static final void readBlob(SQLInput stream, InputStream inputStream) throws SQLException {
        oracle.sql.BLOB blob = oracle.sql.BLOB.getEmptyBLOB();
        blob = (BLOB) stream.readBlob();
        if (blob != null) {
            byte[] bytes = blob.getBytes();
            if (bytes != null) {
                inputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes);
            }
        }
    }
```